# Unsual Result when passing pointer as argument

Tags: c, pointers

I have implemented a hashmap.
             struct hashmap_elmnts
                  { char *key;
                    int in_use;
                    void *data;  //contains the address of the malloc of struct ussd defined below
                   };

```
         struct hashmap_map
             {
               int table_sizel;
               int size;
               struct hashmap_elmnts *element ;
             };
```

Now, I have another structure USSD

```
         typedef struct ussd { char menu;
                         int8_t did;
                         int8_t invokeid;
                         char *language;
                         char *msisdn;
                         char *ussd_string;
                        } USSD;
```

Now, while inserting in the HASHMAP,

```
USSD *init = (USSD*)malloc(sizeof(USSD));
init->msisdn = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
init->language = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
init->ussd_string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
msisdn = language = ussd_string = NULL;
```

Then, I assign some values and then insert in the hashmap

However, while getting the information back, i face some issue:

IN FILE GET.c

I call a function

```
           USSD *pointer = NULL;     
          res =   hashget(key, pointer);
             if (pointer == NULL)
                 printf ("pointer fail\n");
              else
                 printf ("pointer pass\n");
```

IN FILE HASHGET.c

```
    int hashget(int key, USSD_STRUCT *arg)
       {
    /** declaring a hashmap_map pointer  **/
     struct hashmap_map *m;
```

now, after various calculation -> i find a value of 'curr'

```
           arg = (m->element[curr].data);

           if (arg == NULL)
               printf("fail\n");
            else
               printf ("pass\n"):
             return 1;
        }
```

THE OUTPUT IS AS FOLLOWS:
pass
pointer fail

How is this possible, when arg != NULL but still the pointer is NULL. As i expected any assignment at arg would be reflected in pointer also.

Can anybody let me what could have gone wrong. I'm unable to share the entire code snippets as the code is huge..

Comment: Maybe it'll help to show an isolated, compilable piece of code instead of random snippets.

Comment: A *typo?* You couldn't copy-and-paste? If you can't post the entire program, then isolate the problem. Prepare a minimal complete example, and if the bug doesn't leap out at you, post *that*.

Answer (score 3):

In your first block of code you are saying you `if assign null to pointer` not `if pointer equals null`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have corrected my statement above.. its if (pointer == NULL)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (pointer = NULL)
```

This is your problem. If your compiler isn't warning you about this, either turn your warnings up, or find a better compiler. What you want is what you have in your second `if` block:

```
if (pointer == NULL)
```

The reason it isn't working with the one `=` is because you are assigning `NULL` to `pointer` *within* the if statement. The result of that expression is `NULL`, hence the `if` block doesn't execute, but the `else` block does.

Alternatively, some people find it easier to read by omitting the comparison to `NULL` altogether:

```
if (pointer)
{
    // pointer is not NULL
}
else
{
    // pointer is NULL
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have corrected my statement above.. its 
    if (pointer == NULL)

Answer (score 1):

Use this way (Make following changes at respective places)

```
...
res = hashget(key, &pointer);  
if (pointer == NULL)
   printf ("pointer fail\n");
else
   printf ("pointer pass\n");
...
```

`...`
`int hashget(int key, USSD_STRUCT *arg)`
`...`

```
...
*arg = data;
if (*arg == NULL)
   printf("fail\n");
else
   printf ("pass\n"):
return 1;
}
...
```

**Reason:**
In your program you are passing `pointer` as pass by value, In my method I am passing as pass by pointer or basically passing the address of `pointer` because its value needs to be modified in calling function.

**EDIT:** (After your modification in the question)

`USSD init = (USSD)malloc(sizeof(USSD));`

This is wrong. `init` should be a pointer.
Use `USSD *init = (USSD*)malloc(sizeof(USSD));`.

And after you allocated memory to `init->msisdn`, `init->language`, `init->ussd_string`, why are you setting them to `NULL`, that too just by referencing the inner variables of `struct` like this: `msisdn = language = ussd_string = NULL`.

And even if you correct all these mistakes, my answer is OK, since you cannot modify value of `pointer` by making a call like this: `res =   hashget(key, pointer);`, using this you can only modify `*pointer` i.e. value pointed to by the `pointer`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have added few more details... the actual problem I'm facing...  my arguments were passed correctly (was passing the pointer)

Comment: No, you aren't. Think of a pointer as a number which happens you point to a piece of memory. You set the (horribly named) variable pointer to zero and pass the number zero as an argument to hashget, this number zero gets COPIED to the (horribly named) local variable arg. Then you change the value of the local variable arg. You end the function, all local variables, including arg get discarded. The variable pointer is unchanged it still equals zero (NULL).